# Crash getting many data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm populating a recyclerview (not FirebaseRecyclerView) with data coming from FirebaseDatabase. The data to receive is many, are users, and can reach many thousands. When I receive the data the app lagges and then crashes. I know that there are too many data and so it's hard work. Is there a way to optimize it all?

I have this errore in logcat

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread
```

I'm not very impressed, so I ask for help for possible solutions!
Thank you

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.friend_list2);
    //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

    final DatabaseReference mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user-profile");
    mPostReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            username = new ArrayList<>();
            uid = new ArrayList<String>();
            url = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                final FriendItem friendItem = data.getValue(FriendItem.class);
                //final String friendItem2 = data.getKey();



                username.add(friendItem);
                //uid.add(friendItem2);

                adapter = new FriendHoldAdapter3(getApplicationContext(), username, uid, url);
                //adapter.setClickListener(FriendActivity3.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                /**
                adapter = new FriendHoldAdapter2(FriendActivity2.this, username, uid);
                adapter.setClickListener(FriendActivity2.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                 **/
                final List<FriendItem> filteredModelList = filter(username, "        ");
                adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase by design do the network call async, but anything happens inside the onDataChange call in on the main thread, shift your work to some worker thread with an Asynctask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was right to see Asink Task documentation as a new programmer not so much like using it. Can you manage me for realization? Thank you very much

Comment: @hulon tough break, you need to do the work on a separate thread, the UI main thread is for drawing layout and binding data, it is not for sorting or filtering like the stuff you are doing all at once. Why not use the Firebase's own RecyclerViewAdapter? that adapter calls and binds data as you scroll and as needed.

Comment: Yes, I know FirebaseRecyclerView is the best, but I have to do so because I need to do a search in the data, and with FirebaseRecyclerView I can not or better it is much more limited.